# trouble implementing counting sort for strings

Tags: java, sorting

I get this error when I attempt to sort it based off the second char in the string but it runs
fine when I use the first char

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 8
at StringCountSort.countingSort(StringCountSort.java:27)
at StringCountSort.main(StringCountSort.java:38)

```html
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringCountSort{
    
    public static void countingSort(String[] array, int size, int digit)
    {

        String[] result = new String[size+1];
        
        int maximum = 122;
        
        int[] count = new int[maximum + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
            count[i] = 0;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            count[array[i].charAt(digit)] +=1;
        }
        
        for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++){
            count[i] += count[i-1];
        }
    
        for (int i = size -1; i >= 0; i--){

            result[count[array[i].charAt(digit)] - 1] = array[i];
            count[array[i].charAt(0)]--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = result[i];
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] data = { "eg", "fa", "bz", "ch", "hv", "df", "ag" };
        StringCountSort.countingSort(data, data.length, 1);
        System.out.println("Sorted Array in Ascending Order: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        
        
        
    }
}
```

```html
line 28 result[count[array[i].charAt(digit)] - 1] = array[i]; 

line 37 StringCountSort.countingSort(data, data.length, 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger on this? And you could mark line 28 and 37 with comments?

Comment: line 28  result[count[array[i].charAt(digit)] - 1] = array[i];                                             
line 37  StringCountSort.countingSort(data, data.length, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
count[array[i].charAt(0)]--;
```

to

```
count[array[i].charAt(digit)]--;
```

This should do the trick.

I also suggest the following improvements:

1. You don't need to pass the length of `array` as an argument.
2. You don't need to set every `int` of `count` to `0`;
3. `maximum` should be `Character.MAX_VALUE`, to support every possible character.

The finished function could look like this:

```
    public static void countingSort(String[] array, int digit) {
        String[] result = new String[array.length];
        int[] count = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            count[array[i].charAt(digit)]++;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++){
            count[i] += count[i-1];
        }
        for (int i = array.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
            result[count[array[i].charAt(digit)] - 1] = array[i];
            count[array[i].charAt(digit)]--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = result[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Things that need to be changed are (if you want to sort the strings on the basis of first character)

1. `count[array[i].charAt(digit)] +=1` to `count[array[i].charAt(0)] +=1`
2. `result[count[array[i].charAt(digit)] - 1] = array[i]; count[array[i].charAt(0)]--;`   to `result[--count[array[i].charAt(0)]] = array[i];`

If you want to sort the string on the basis of the second character then simply change :

1. `count[array[i].charAt(0)]--;` to `count[array[i].charAt(digit)]--;`

Comment: Where exactly do you use the function parameter "digit"? 
As I understand it, OP wants to sort the strings based on the second letter of each string (index of letter / digit = 1).

Comment: @TobiasMiosczka you are right, I mistakenly downvoted your answer, can you make an edit to your answer so that I am able to revert my vote.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your fairness.